# realizar un this.setState en una tabla <tr> con Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una tabla que me recibe parametros y los muestra en pantalla, y la misma tiene evento onclick que llama a una funcion a la cual debo pasarle un parametro que esta en la tabla, aqui estoy intentando realizar un this.setState, y usando la funcion onChange realizar dicha accion y creo que por ahí empieza el problema. pero no estoy seguro.

este es mi render() donde intento que esta linea:

```
<tr id="tablaBuses" onClick={this.aplicarFiltro} 
  onChange={() => { this.setState({ bus: dataBus.numero}); }}>
```

este es el render completo:

```
   render() {
    const { Filtro } = this.props;
    console.info(Filtro.origen + Filtro.destino);

    return (

        <div id="tablaBus">
            <Table striped bordered hover responsive size="sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>H. de Salida</th>
                        <th>H de llegada</th>
                        <th>patente</th>
                        <th>Conductor</th>
                        <th>Origen</th>
                        <th>Destino</th>
                        <th>Nº Bus</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {this.state.loading === false &&
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.buses.map((dataBus) => {
                            return (
                                <tr id={dataBus.numero} 
                                onChange={() => { this.setState({ bus: dataBus.numero}); console.log('INGRESO A LA FUNCION') }}>
                                    <td>{this.formateaFecha(dataBus.fecha_salida)}</td>
                                    <td>{this.formateaFecha(dataBus.fecha_destino)}</td>
                                    <td>{dataBus.patente}</td>
                                    <td>{dataBus.conductor_nombre}</td>
                                    <td>{dataBus.origen}</td>
                                    <td>{dataBus.destino}</td>
                                    <td >{dataBus.numero}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                }
            </Table>

        </div>
    );
}
```

este es mi constructor:

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
        linea: 0,
        loading: true,
        buses: {},
        origen: '',
        destino: '',
        status: null,
        bus:0,
    }
    this.aplicarFiltro = this.aplicarFiltro.bind(this)
}
```

y esta es la funcion que llama al state:

```
aplicarFiltro() {
    if (parseInt(this.state.bus) <= 0) {
      alert("Seleccione un bus antes de buscar");
      return;
    }
    this.props.onBuscar(1 ,3, this.state.bus);
  }
```

Comment: visual studio tiene algo que ver con tu pregunta?

Comment: es el ide que uso

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a visual studio code no? De todas maneras, si el ide no es relevante en tu pregunta (como asi parece) es mejor que no lo agregues como tag en la misma

Comment: No creo que el evento onChange funcione correctamente en un table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque no lo haces así simplemente:

```
aplicarFiltro(bus) {
    if (bus <= 0) {
      alert("Seleccione un bus antes de buscar");
      return;
    }
    this.setState({bus}) //Solo si realmente es necesario manejar como estado el bus que se va a buscar
    this.props.onBuscar(1 ,3, bus);
  }
```

```
  <tbody>
      {this.state.buses.map((dataBus) => {
          return (
              <tr id={dataBus.numero} 
                  onClick={() => {
                      this.aplicarFiltro(dataBus.numero)
                  }>
                  <td>{this.formateaFecha(dataBus.fecha_salida)}</td>
                  <td>{this.formateaFecha(dataBus.fecha_destino)}</td>
                  <td>{dataBus.patente}</td>
                  <td>{dataBus.conductor_nombre}</td>
                  <td>{dataBus.origen}</td>
                  <td>{dataBus.destino}</td>
                  <td >{dataBus.numero}</td>
              </tr>
          )
      })}
  </tbody>
```

Comment: he implementado lo que me has pasado, pero me genera un erro, la funcion aplicar filtro se ejecuta cada vez que llama un objeto, y me da error con la funcion onBuscar.

Comment: ya he logrado resolver el problema, con tu ayuda, le he pasado todo como me has indicado pero para poder que funcionara en el onClick le he pasado esto
onClick={()=>this.click(this.aplicarFiltro(dataBus.numero))}

realiza todo, pero ahora me dice que this.click no es una funcion

Comment: ya he resuelto el problema, a sido un alert(), que me tenia la vida triste y no supe darme cuenta, en un principio, ya el codigo que me has pasado a quedado, excelente pero lo que si no fue posible fue hacerle un this.setState, de igual forma no fue necesario, muchas gracias